# axios get an error when trying to get the list

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, axios

I need to get a list from this resource http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos

Controller

```js
    @JsonController('/photo')
    @Service()
    export class PhotoController {
    constructor(private photoService: PhotoService) {}

    @Get('/load-photos')
    loadPhoto() {
        return axios
            .get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos')
            .then(async (response) => console.log(response.data.slice(0, 8)))
            .catch((e) => console.log(e));
    }
}
```

Postman rout: http://localhost:5000/photo/load-photos

As soon as I try to just try to make a request through axios for a resource through postman, I call the controller and I get the error that I give below. If I do an action outside the application, then through axios I can easily get data into the console, for example.

Error

```
Error:
    at new HttpError (C:\pet-project\express\node_modules\src\http-error\HttpError.ts:16:18)
    at new NotFoundError (C:\pet-project\express\node_modules\src\http-error\NotFoundError.ts:10:5)
    at ExpressDriver.handleSuccess (C:\pet-project\express\node_modules\src\driver\express\ExpressDriver.ts:324:15)
    at C:\pet-project\express\node_modules\src\RoutingControllers.ts:164:35
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
```

Application class:

```js
export class App {
    public app: express.Application;

    constructor() {
        this.app = express();
    }

    public async createExpressServer(port: number) {
        useContainer(Container);
        useExpressServer(this.app, {
            controllers: [AuthController, PhotoController],
            middlewares: [],
            authorizationChecker: async (action: Action, roles?: string[]): Promise<boolean> => {
                return false;
            }
        });
        this.app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Running on port ${port}`));
    }
}
```

call app:

```js
const app = new App();
const port: any = process.env.APP_PORT;
app.createExpressServer(5000);
```

What do I use in the application: Express and routing-controllers libs

Question: Why am I getting this error when trying to get data from a resource from a controller?
Thanks in advance for your reply!

Comment: are you sending a response back to reply the request you are making in postman? from the code you have provided, it does not look like it. http client requires a response after a request is made, or the request will eventually timeout from the clients side...

Comment: I don't get why you use `await` and `then/catch` simultaneously. Either use one or another. And you don't return a result from your controller.

Comment: @Anatoly, Even if I add return axios get (...) and remove await, the error persists

Comment: @ash.io, I make a request to output data to the console, no more, I do not need to return data to the client, just get it for the server

Comment: Are you sure you make a request correctly? I don't see axios errors in the stacktrace. Show how you call your route

Comment: @Anatoly, I modified my question a bit and added the controller completely. If I now remove axios get (...) and just write return 'test'; then through postman I will get 200 status with my text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't return a proper non-empty result or a Promise with such result that's why you got a 404 error as the [official documentation](https://github.com/typestack/routing-controllers#controlling-empty-responses) says.
Try to get a result with `await` and return it explicitly:

```js
    @JsonController('/photo')
    @Service()
    export class PhotoController {
    constructor(private photoService: PhotoService) {}

    @Get('/load-photos')
    async loadPhoto() {
       try {
         const { data } = await axios
            .get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos');
         return data.slice(0, 8)
       } catch (e: Error) {
          console.log(e)
          // returns 404 for instance, it's up to you, 
          // see https://github.com/typestack/routing-controllers#throw-http-errors
          throw new NotFoundError(`Photos were not found.`); 
       }
    }
}
```